# Why am I getting this "null or not an object" error in IE?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onload

I have a button (`<asp:button id="MyButton" runat="server" />`). I want this button to be automatically clicked onload. So I added JavaScript for that to happen:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
      myButton.click();
</script>
```

The error I'm getting is "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'myButton' is null or not an object"

The page this button is on has a MasterPage in the back. Would that be the reason this is happenening?

Comment: Does a HTML element with the ID myButton exist in the HTML code? When are you executing this script?

Comment: Does your button have the id set as "myButton"?

Comment: Is the ID of your button actually myButton?

Answer (score 2):

You want to write the client ID rather than the server ID.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var myButton = document.getElementById('<%=MyButton.ClientID%>');
      myButton.click();
</script>
```

I see, this code will run before the button is loaded on the client so you will need to place this script block after the button or if you are using jQuery or something similar they will offer document ready functionality. The following code will be run once the document has loaded completely.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myButton = $('#<%=MyButton.ClientID%>');
    myButton.click();
});
```

You'll want to set a few properties to implement your requirements.

```
<asp:button 
    id="MyButton" 
    runat="server" 
    UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
    OnClientClick="return changeBackgroundColor();" />
```

Setting the `UseSubmitBehavior` to `false` means that the button will not post back to the server. The `OnClientClick` property is as literal as it sounds. When clicked the client will execute the JavaScript code specified.

Comment: In addition, the script segment should be run *AFTER* the button is rendered.

Comment: @Tracker - That is not actually necessary *(At least post-3.0)*.

Comment: i changed the javascript to this one (clientid). The error is still the same. The myButton is still null in the javascript code.

Comment: @Ikeod - I changed the casing of the server ID so it should work now.

Comment: @Tracker - Looks like I misread your comment. You are of course correct.

Comment: i placed the corrected javascript after the button and it goes into an infinite loop mode. The main page itself keeps loading over and over again. I am not sure why.

Comment: @Ikeod - By default buttons will submit the page so I have to ask you what you want to happen when the button is clicked?

Comment: o ok. it shall change the color of the background. Its pretty basic

Comment: @Ikeod - I've edited my answer. Let me know if this helps by clicking the check box next to my answer. The more accepted answers you have the more willing other users will be to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById()` is case sensitive.  Try `document.getElemenById('MyButton')`.

Comment: On a side note, I am not totally sure why you want to click a button as the page loads.  An <asp:Button runat="server" /> will actually do a postback.  Wouldn't this cause the page to load, then postback, then load, etc?

Comment: Very true, unless they meant for the button to have some sort of client side behavior.

Answer (score 0):

What is the Id of the button in the rendered HTML on the client side?  ASP .NET has a tendency to have longer auto-generated client-side IDs for its own use.  One thing you could do is set the `name` attribute of the button and reference that in the JavaScript.

Also of potential use to you is [a method of finding a .NET client ID using jQuery](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/42319.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The button probably has another ID when it's rendered to the client. Try to set `ClientIDMode="Static"` for the button. Then the id will be then same as on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Change the id="MyButton" to id="myButton" case matters in javascript/DOM

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var myButton = document.getElementById('<%= myButton.ClientID %>');
    myButton.click();
</script>
```

And put this script at the end of page just before `</body>`.

Answer (score 0):

The page may not have loaded fully so when this code is executed 'myButton' may not be available yet.  You can either make a function that calls this on body load:

```
<body onload="functionForButton()">
```

or put your script at the end of the body tag:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
      myButton.click();
</script> 
</body>
```

Also make sure the case is the same.  MyButton != myButton

Comment: there is not body. This is the content page, body is in the masterpage behind.